# Laravel inserts `0000-00-00` instead of null when DB is set to `->nullable()` and `->default(null)`

Tags: php, date, laravel-5, nullable, homestead

I'm using Laravel 5.1 on a Homestead Vagrant box, PHP  7.2.14 on Ubuntu 18.04 with MySql 5.7.25.

I have created a migration with this:

```
$table->date('expiry_date')->nullable()->default(null);
```

I have a form with a date field called `expiry_date`, with a default set to null:

```
{!! Form::date('expiry_date', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

When I enter a date in the field everything works fine, but when I leave it blank it inserts `0000-00-00` into the database, which then messes up the display in my view. The only way I've been able to fix it is by adding this to the model:

```
public function setExpiryDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['expiry_date'] = $value ?: null;
}
```

I'm annoyed that I have to do this extra step, and it doesn't feel very "Laravel" which makes me believe I'm missing something.

Interesting thing is that it passes validation in my custom Request:

```
'expiry_date' => 'date',
```

EDIT:

I have `protected $dates ['expiry_date']` set in the model and it's been added to mass assignment as well.

Comment: As far as I know you can't null the time. It's default is 0000-00-00 00:00.

Comment: html5's `input type="date"` default might be `0000-00-00` if empty... so technically it's not null. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Thanks @O-9 I'll give that a try and get back to you